# simplest solution to making updates on salesforce cases with Java?

Tags: java, lambda, salesforce

I am looking to do two basic tasks on a salesforce account:

1) Update a checkbox (set to false) inside a case
2) Add a comment to said case

Unfortunately the SOAP api is not available for me and I do not have the access/ability to change settings on the salesforce account.

I am extremely new at this and am having trouble deciding what the best approach to do this would be. I found something similar in python, using the library (simple salesforce) but I need to utilize Java in this case as this code is to reside inside a Java lambda function.

I am wondering if I could get away with not using a salesforce library? and simply making requests to the account - however I am finding it very difficult to find documentation explaining how to do so.

To add to this: I do have all the necessary credentials available.